# How to justify the content in Android Studio - XML

Tags: android, xml, justify

I would like to know if it is possible to justify the content of a `LinearLayout` in Android Studio as I usually do for web.

**Web CSS**

```
.space-around {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

What `space-around` does is to evenly distribute in the line with equal space around them making the content to fit into the div ([link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/))

How could I get the same effect in Android Studio in my `LinearLayout`?

**Android**

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this does not fully answer your question because it is not using `LinearLayout`, but Google has provided an [Android implementation of the so-called flexbox layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout), which has a lot of settings which you might already be familiar with from CSS.

It also supports justify-content, if you scroll down through the readme there are a lot of examples included.

To use this, you will have to add a dependency on it, of course. Use version 1.0.0 if you are not on AndroidX yet, otherwise just use the latest stable one.

Answer (score 5):

You can something like this:
Just give Inner elements of LinearLayout same weight:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to apply similar to CSS justify content behaviour to views in XML is by using `ConstraintLayout`, assigning constraints and manipulating [chain styles](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain) (`app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle` `app:layout_constraintHorisontal_chainStyle`)

You can also do similar things with `LinearLayout` in some cases you would need to add transparent `View`s and adjust their weights `android:layout_weight`